# add text to div. New line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text in my page with "key"(@n) for new line, and I have to change the "key" as a new line and add this text to my div. I'm not finding how to:

```js
var original= "the text @n to change";
var changed = original.replace(/@n /g, '\n ');

$('#theText').text(changed)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theText">

</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: HTML 101: Line breaks are condensed to a single white space in any “normal” circumstances. You need to either use an element that treats text content differently by default (such a `pre`), or you need to apply the necessary CSS to your div to make it treat this differently than it normally would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML normal linebreaks won't work in most cases. Instead use the `<br />` tag.

Your code, updated:

```js
var original= "the text @n to change";
var changed = original.replace(/@n /g, '<br />');

$('#theText').html(changed)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theText">

</div>
```

You have to use `.html()` to add the text.

Security note: By using `html()` your site is potentially threatened by cross site scripting if users can modify the text you want to display.

---

Alternatively you can also use the [`<pre>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag or the [`white-space: pre;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) css attribte.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\n`, you can use `<br />` and instead of `text()`, you will have to use `html()`

```js
var original= "the text @n to change";
var changed = original.replace(/@n /g, '<br /> ');

$('#theText').html(changed)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theText">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you do it with .html() and a br it would work

```js
var original= "the text @n to change";
var changed = original.replace(/@n /g, '<br />');

$('#theText').html(changed)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theText">

</div>
```